# access path in zip file in import module

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a zip file (data.zip) with structure like,

```
config/
   config.json
src/
   util.py
```

When I import this zip like, I face below error,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./data.zip')
import src.util

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../config/config.json'
```

reason behind this is, util.py has a method which accesses config.json in config directory of zip. I am not sure why this is failing and util.py is failing to read/access config/config.json. Can anybody help me understand this behavior and solution to solve this?

Comment: print `sys.path` before and after each `append` call so you can see what's present in your path. Also, can't you unzip the directory before trying to import files from it?

Comment: I can see data.zip appended in sys.path after printing the path. No I can't unzip the directory as I need to pass this zip to pyspark job using --py-files and which will copy it to each executors. This will not work with directory AFAIK. Please correct if this is wrong.

Comment: See [**`zipimporter.get_data`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html#zipimport.zipimporter.get_data)

Comment: Problem is, I don;t want to access that file from outside but util.py from zip itself accesses that file (config.json). So I am not sure zimimporter.get_data will be helpful.